# Unity2D how to limit player jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So im making a clicker game and here is my code. What i want to ask is how to limiting button to click so it can't be clicked by multiple time, because if i clicked it multiple time the speed became too fast

```
public float downForce;
public float speed;

public int playerHp;

public Text healthText;

Rigidbody2D rb;

CharacterController controller;

void Awake()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    healthText.text = playerHp.ToString();
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Jump();
    }

    if (playerHp < 0)
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("GameOver");
    }
}

public void Jump()
{
    rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * downForce + Vector2.right * speed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    rb.isKinematic = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Button BTN;
public float btnDelay = .5f;
```

this to get the Button reference and specify the duration

```
coroutine = ButtonDelayed(btnDelay);
StartCoroutine(coroutine);
```

this after you call `Jump();` in your update or in `Jump()`

```
IEnumerator ButtonDelayed(float delay)
{
BTN.interactable = false;
yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
BTN.interactable = !BTN.interactable;
}
```

this somewhere.
Just a quick mockup. Not sure if you will get an exception. If you have a problem just hit me up.

EDIT: I forgot to tell you to change the color of the disabled state in the inspector to the color you have when the Button is interactable. Otherwise you will see the Button change colors.

EDIT2: Full script updated

```
public float downForce;
public float speed;   
public int playerHp;   
public Text healthText;

Rigidbody2D rb;    
CharacterController controller;

public Button BTN;
public float btnDelay = .5f;

void Awake()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
    healthText.text = playerHp.ToString();
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Jump();
    }

    if (playerHp < 0)
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("GameOver");
    }
}

public void Jump()
{
    coroutine = ButtonDelayed(btnDelay);
    StartCoroutine(coroutine);
    rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * downForce + Vector2.right * speed, 
    ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    rb.isKinematic = false;
}

IEnumerator ButtonDelayed(float delay)
{
    BTN.interactable = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    BTN.interactable = !BTN.interactable;
}
```

Comment: im still new into unity so how do i exactly place the coroutine ? and its still my first time to use IEnumerator too

Comment: Edited the post and changed your script.

Answer (score 0):

I still can't reply to comments so I'll post it here

To use IEnumerator is just like any other function

you put it somewhere in your code and then call it
the difference is when you call it you add

StartCoroutine(MethodName()) ;

and it will run the first part of the code - then Wait For the amount of time you specified, then it will run the second part of the code